# find and grep and print the file name and line number

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

I have a requirement to print all file name and line number which contain a text.

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -exec grep -n 'HELLO' {} \; > output.txt
```

but it's only printing the content and line number not the file name . How to achieve it? I am doing it on Solaris.

Comment: Do you want the content, or only the file name?

Comment: only line number and file name.

Comment: Do you require a recursive search, or are all the files in the current directory?

Comment: as simple out put from 
grep -n  'HELLO' *.cpp

Comment: recursive search in all the sub directories.

Comment: find . -name '*.cpp' | xargs grep -n 'HELLO' will get your desired result, cant explain why

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option using awk instead of grep:

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -exec awk '/HELLO/ { print FILENAME, NR }' {} + > output.txt
```

Whenever the pattern is matched, the filename and line number are printed. I have used `-exec {} +` so that multiple filenames are passed as arguments to a single invocation of awk, which should be quicker if you have lots of files to search.

Answer (score 3):

If your grep doesn't support the `-H` option (the greps on Solaris 10 do not), the typical workaround is to add the file `/dev/null` to grep's command line. That file won't match anything, but because there are two or more files in the command line, grep will show file names in its output.

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -exec grep -n 'HELLO' /dev/null {} \; > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You need one more grep argument:

```
  -H, --with-filename
          Print the filename for each match.
```

I don't see a way to exclude the matching text from the output in grep.  You may have to filter your output again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a non-standard option, so may not be available.

Comment: does solaris' grep support those parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use "-r" option of "grep" it looks up inside the files:

```
find . -name '*.cpp' | grep -n -r HELLO > output.txt
```

Comment: this will grep find's output (ie, a list of filenames)

Comment: Grep will open and look up inside the files which the paths were found with "find". Thi is what the option "-r" provides.

Comment: that would be the case if you execute grep with a list of files. in this case you are piping find's output to grep, so grep will process its standard input.

Comment: Just try it, if it doesn't work I will remove my answer.

Comment: I tried it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
grep -n 'HELLO' `find . -name '*.cpp'` > output.txt
```

I can't test it on solaris so I am not sure it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Let the grep look in 2 files. I usually use /etc/passwd, but /dev/null is better:

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -exec grep -n 'HELLO' {} /dev/null \; > output.txt
```